# MySQL does not utilize server fully

Tags: mysql, database, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have MariaDB 10.0.17 running on Amazon RDS db.m4.xlarge (16Gb RAM, 4vCPU) Multi AZ deployment. We use Provisioned IOPS storage with max set to 10000 IOPS.
`users` table contains 17M records; `user_properties` table contains 350M records.

`user_properties` table describes "map" of props attached to an user. `upkey` is key, `string_value`, `integer_value` etc are values per-type; STRING, DATE, INTEGER, DOUBLE. Indexes are also per-type.

We try to insert insert even more data to `user_properties` table: Application inserts data into INNODB temp table `TEMP1`, then data gets copied from `TEMP1` to `user_properties` table.

Problem is that we only reach 2500 write IOPS and 500-1000 read IOPS. Queue depth holds on ~7 in average. MySQL server CPU usage holds on 20-30% and never reaches 60%.
Application seems to feed enough data to MySQL: we feed similar data files to DB and see how processing time increases as table size increases. 
Most time application waits for MySQL query completion. In this process insertion into `TEMP1` table takes small fraction of overall time, most time is waiting for insertion from `TEMP1` table to `user_properties`.

Could somebody help me making MySQL faster? What should I increase/change?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20), // Column is not used now. Filled with NULL
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `partner_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique-email` (`partner_id`,`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_Uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `idx_013_partner_id_uuid` (`partner_id`,`uuid`),
  KEY `idx_014_uuid` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKB2D9FEBE725C505E` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partner` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_046_partner` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partner` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_properties` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `upkey` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `security_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `_content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_value` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `integer_value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `double_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `string_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_004_uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `idx_005_string_value` (`upkey`,`string_value`),
  KEY `idx_006_integer_value` (`upkey`,`integer_value`),
  KEY `idx_007_double_value` (`upkey`,`double_value`),
  KEY `idx_008_date_value` (`upkey`,`date_value`),
  KEY `idx_key_value_user_upkey_string` (`user_id`,`upkey`,`string_value`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I thought speed is the priority, not how may IOPS a transaction consumes!

Comment: @Shadow I just want to know what's the bottleneck for my speed situation - what should I increase/change to make it faster? IOPS are not utilized fully, CPU is underused, RAM is okay - so there is no clear candidate and I am puzzled what to do next..

Comment: @Shadow It's almost plain `insert into user_properties from select * from...`. I insert by batches of ~10-50K records per transaction, in 3 application threads. I don't do COPY, it's regular SQL statement from Java. No other activity is in DB except from this insertion.

Comment: Did you measure how much drive bandwith you occupy? You can have sufficient IOPS lying around, but if you spent the bandwith capacity then that's about it for that drive.

Comment: Do you turn off the foreign key checks before starting the data transfer on session level?

Comment: @Shadow No, I don't turn this check off. I can give a try. You think this may be a cause? So far I just assumed all checks should count to read IOPS which kind of low anyway.

Comment: Turning off foreign key checks can speed up a mass insert, yes. You can also experiment in inserting data from more than 3 application threads. Also, I would take a look at those indexes as well. Are you sure, you need covering indexes on upkey - value pairs? Also, if you have an id column with auto increment, why do you have an uuid one as well?

Comment: @Mjh "Drive throughput" is amount of MB/s that gets read/written to drive? I can see in console it looks like high - 90MB/s. Is it high? maybe you know limits.. Screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/JZA0gL4opYUGD

Comment: @Shadow `uuid` is needed for public access, as id is predictable identifier and can be hacked with bruteforce. Basically there is room for optimizing this table indeed, though I would be really glad to hit some server bottleneck and the optimize from there, that's the point of my question. A good catch was brough by @Mjh about write throughput cap, maybe I hit it..

Comment: what is the innodb_buffer_size_pool?

Comment: @Vorsprung it's RDS default, `innodb_buffer_pool_size {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}` which means 12Gb

Comment: snowindy perhaps try a r3 instance instead, see if more memory helps?

Comment: There is nothing that I see in your question to explain how much parallelism/concurrency is going on in your database access. You will not saturate the system without *at least* as many concurrent queries as there are processor cores, and probably not even then (so you need even more). With only one concurrent query, you're going to hit no more than 25% CPU (using 100% of 1 out of of 4 cores) and that's your bottleneck.  A given running query in MySQL only really uses the equivalent of one core, max.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I insert by batches of ~10-50K records per transaction, in 3 application thread. That means I at least use 3 CPUs. Other question is that insertion to table with indexes does not look like something CPU-intensive, I assumed I should be saturating drive IOPS or throughput (thanks to some of prev comments). Also note should be taken that insertion of one table with indexes concurrently may imply locking, for example on PK or other indexes. I would be pleased to know if locking occur in concurrent inserts but so far I don't know how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need both `id` and `uuid`?  I think not.

Do you need 3 `UNIQUE` keys for a table?  I think not.  (Remember a `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE`.)

`uuid` has some very bad I/O properties when the tables get huge.  Reconsider your use of them.  An index on `uuid` is *very* random.  When the index (or table) becomes too large to fit in the buffer_pool, the fetches tend to involve I/O rather than being cached.  With 350M rows and 16GB of RAM, I suspect a significant part of the performance problem is due to uuids.

`user_properties` is a "key-value" store, correct?  That schema design pattern sucks.  What is the typical `SELECT`?  I suspect it is something like this:

```
SELECT ..._value FROM user_properties
    WHERE user_id = '...'
      AND upkey = '...';
```

Assuming that is correct, the performance can be improved some by having

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, upkey, id)
```

This will "cluster" the key-value pairs for a given user in a single location (probably 1-2 blocks), thereby making their fetching faster.

More on the [evils of key-value](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) and a suggestion for improvement.
More on the [evils of UUIDs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).

Comment: uuid was introduced for security reasons, IDs are too easy for brute force. I don't need ID, auto-increment was removed and it's NULL for now.
Typical select is: 1. find properties of user - case you mention, 2. find user by property - upkey/string_value.

My question generally was not about how table design stinks (it does, I confirm!) but how to identify a bottleneck when server looks like underloaded. A good suspect was to drive throughput which is 90Mb/s. Well yeah, It looks like this bottleneck is best solvable with good schema, not RAID or smth. What do you think?

Comment: The schema and its indexes are a big bottleneck.  Doesn't RDS use SSDs?  If so, that's a lot better than spinning drives, even with RAID striping.  I can't tell for sure whether you are I/O bound now; if you are, it is probably because of UUIDs -- That can be overcome by more RAM (until the tables again get too big).

Comment: For upkey+string --> user_id, would `INDEX(upkey, string_value, user_id)` be a "covering index"?  If so that would be a small, but easy, speedup.

Comment: "Looks underloaded" -- One mysql/mariadb thread won't use more than one CPU core.  Can you explain why there seem to be more writes than reads?  What do you have for sync_binlog, innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, innodb_double_write, innodb_%_io_threads?

Comment: Re more writes than reads: Basically because all we care now is insert speed, it's in the question. We want it be even faster and looking how. Read speed is just fine for the needs we have. We bulk insert with 3 threads 10k-50k user props per one transaction.

Comment: 50K rows may be too many; what is the value of `innodb_log_file_size`?  Also provide `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'innodb%';` -- from those, we can see how often the log files are rotating.

Comment: Here you go: innodb_log_file_size=134217728, InnoDb status: https://gist.github.com/snowindy/eac01b051e571bad54d0

Comment: (Need the `SHOWs` to determine if the log is 'rotating' too often.)